# If-Else doesn't return desired output

Tags: python

I was doing the study drills for this chapter and I've stumbled upon this problem that I can't seem to figure out, maybe  I'm missing something.

Here's the code:

```
# write a small adventure game similar to ex31

print("""You enter a dungeon and you find yoursfelf in front of three doors.
Do you go through door #1, door #2 or door #3?""")

dungeon_door = input(">> ")

if dungeon_door == '1' or '2':
    print("You stumble upon a goblin. What do you do?")
    print("1 - Try to kill the goblin with your shoe.")
    print("2 - Try to talk things out.")
    print("3 - Exit through the door you came from.")

    goblin = input(">> ")

    if goblin == '1':
        print("You actually manage to kill the goblin. Dude you're a beast!")

        print("You have to choose between two doors, do you pick the left one or the right one?")

        final_door = input(">> ").lower()

        if final_door == 'left':
            print("This door leads to the treasure chamber. Dungeon cleared, congrats!")
        elif final_door == 'right':
            print("After you open to door an enormous one-eyed monster eats you. This dungeon was too much for you, try again.")
        else:
            print(f"What does {final_door} even mean? You're kicked out of the dungeon, bye.")

    elif goblin == '2':
        print("""Can you speak Ghukliak? Don't think so. The goblin doesn't understand you, you're dead.
        The dungeon was too much for you, bye.""")
    elif goblin == 3:
        print("The door is somehow locked. The goblin takes this chance to kill you. The dungeon was too much for you, bye.")
    else:
        print(f"What does {goblin} even mean? You're kicked out of the dungeon, bye.")

elif dungeon_door == '3':
    print("Well, it's your lucky day. This door leads directly to the treasure chamber. Dungeon cleared, congrats!")
else:
    print(f"What does {dungeon_door} even mean? You're kicked out of the dungeon, bye.")
```

So part of the code works fine, the only problem I have is when I ask the user to make the first choice.
When I input '3' as the answer or something completely different from the suggested answers, I get the output as if the user has answered with '1' or '2'. I hope I have been clear enough.

I know it's a bit long and boring, sorry and **TIA**!

Comment: Welcome (back?) to Stack Overflow. There are multiple things wrong in this code. But more importantly, there are multiple things you should first learn about a) how to solve problems yourself and b) how to ask questions on Stack Overflow. Please read [ask], https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and [mre] for a start.

Comment: Ok sorry, I will.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is wrong here:

```
if dungeon_door == '1' or '2':
```

Should be:

```
if dungeon_door == '1' or dungeon_door == '2':
```

Or

```
if dungeon_door in ('1', '2'):
```

And you forgot quotes around the 3

```
elif goblin == 3:
```

Comment: I see, didn't think that was an error, no wonder I couldn't find out. Thank you for your help!